# Sort dictionary by value, then by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

Hey I am trying to sort a dictionary by value from highest to lowest value. Howevet I want the items with same values to be sorted by key.

The following code does not work

```
dictionary = {"Sophie": 23, "Alfred": 23, "Zelda":22, "Betty":23}
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: t[::-1])
```

Output:

```
[('Zelda', 22), ('Alfred', 23), ('Betty', 23), ('Sophie', 23)]
```

Expected output:

```
[('Alfred', 23), ('Betty', 23), ('Sophie', 23), ('Zelda', 22)]
```

ordered by decreasing value, then by key (alphabetical)

Comment: What is the output you were expecting?  It looks like you were trying to sort by value (second value of the resulting 2-tuple), and then by the first. It looks correct to me (22 before 23, A, B, then S for 23).

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to sort with one key (the value) in descending order and a secondary key (the name) in ascending order, simply reversing the sorting order would not work. Instead, you should construct a tuple of the value and the name, with the value negated to sort it in descending order:

```
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
```

Comment: Hey @blhsing. The only problem that is left is that your solution returns a list of tuples. How can I make it return a dictionary?

Comment: You can pass the resulting list of tuples to the `dict` constructor to build a new dict with it: `dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0])))`

Answer (score 1):

### Option1

This is he more modern solution that will only work in `python3.x`, this is the same aproach the question took.Instead of `t[::-1]` being the index you need to use `t: (-t[1], t[0])` .`-t[1]` sorts the names in ascending order because it has been negted. `t[0]`sorts keys in descending order.
**Here is the code:**

```
dictionary = {"Sophie": 23, "Alfred": 23, "Zelda":22, "Betty":23}
reversed_dict= dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0])))
print(reversed_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Alfred': 23, 'Betty': 23, 'Sophie': 23, 'Zelda': 22}
```

---

### Option2

This is the more portable solution and works in all versions of python.This aproach requires you to import the `operator` library bfore you can begin.
`sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))` sorts the names in ascending order then `sorted(reversed_dict, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))` orders the keys in descending order.

**Here is the code:**

```
import operator

dictionary = {"Sophie": 23, "Alfred": 23, "Zelda":22, "Betty":23}
reversed_dict = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
reversed_dict = dict(sorted(reversed_dict, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
print(reversed_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Alfred': 23, 'Betty': 23, 'Sophie': 23, 'Zelda': 22}
```

Comment: Hey, yes this works, however the ITEMS WITH SAME VALUE are still not sorted alphabetically by keys. Exactly that is my problem...

Comment: @Luke21 its a pleasure

Comment: It's poor form to copy someone else's code without giving credit. You also failed to update your output after copying the use of the `dict` constructor to your code.